# R - error installing package - Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : Couldn't connect to server

Tags: r

I am trying to install the BTYplus package in R.

```
devtools::install_github("mplatzer/BTYDplus", dependencies=TRUE)
library(BTYDplus)
demo(package="BTYDplus")
```

But it gives me the following error:

> Downloading github repo mplatzer/BTYDplus@master
>   Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
>   Couldn't connect to server

Did anyone had a similar issue when installing packages on R?

Comment: Works for me (W7, 64 bit). Proxy issues?

Comment: Yes I am on Windows 64. How can I check if is proxy?

Comment: It's a year later -- did you resolve your issue? I'm getting this error:  Error in curl::curl_fetch_disk(url, x$path, handle = handle) : 
  Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)

Comment: @zbicyclist did you figure out the zbicyclist issue?

Answer (score 4):

You can download the library externally and then import it to R:
Download from: https://github.com/mplatzer/BTYDplus
import from: Tools > Install Packages/ Package Archive File(.zip; .tar.gz)

Answer (score 4):

Setting the proxy did work for me. Here is how I have done that:

```
library(httr)
set_config(use_proxy(url='http://my.proxy', port, username, password))
```

(and fill in your own url, port, username and password. Username and password were not necessary for me)

Answer (score 0):

For me it was not proxy problem, instead the following lines solved my problem:

```
library(httr)
set_config(config(ssl_verifypeer = 0L))
```

Found it [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/fixing-peer-certificate-cannot-be-authenticated/).